# ConfirmDialog on TabClose event

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How can I process the operation of closing a tab depending of a user's confirmDialog action ? "yes" to continue closing the tab, "No" to abort the operation. I have made this code below but the tab is closed anyway. Any suggestions please ?

```
<p:confirmDialog    closable="true" appendToBody="true" id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure to close ?" header="Test"  widgetVar="confirmation">  
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" onclick="closeTab=true;" oncomplete=" PF('confirmation').hide();"/>  
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="PF('confirmation').hide()" /> 
    </h:form>
    </p:confirmDialog>

<p:tabView  onTabClose="return close(function(){return true;});">
        <p:tab title="test tab" closable="true" >
           // Some inputs controls here
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

JS function

```
var closeTab = false;
function close(callback) 
{
     PF('confirmation').show();
       var state = false;
       loop();
       function loop() {
            if (!closeTab) {
                console.log('fired');
                setTimeout(loop, 0);
            }
            else {
                callback();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You can't, not without customizing the PrimeFaces source (or overriding the client side javascript). Sorry I have no solution, but creating that would take way to much time

Comment: Hi Kukeltje , I've edited my post including a JS function with a setTimeout in order to wait the user action on Yes button. The function onTabClose still return without waiting ? Did I made something wrong ? Thanks for help.

Comment: Hey guys .. Any help or something that I can start with ?!

Comment: no, sorry, to complex if the suggestion to 'override the client side javascript (**from primefaces**) does not help to get you into that direction but start hacking in the wrong direction

Comment: @Kukeltje has this changed at all since this question was asked?

Comment: Not that I know of. Try and/or look at the PF source to  see how to prevent the close from happening. Miggt require some jquery code

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way

```
<p:confirmDialog closable="true" appendToBody="true" id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure to close ?" header="Test"  widgetVar="confirmation">  
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" onclick="PF('confirmation').remove();" oncomplete=" PF('confirmation').hide();"/>  
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="PF('confirmation').hide()" /> 
    </h:form>
    </p:confirmDialog>

<p:tabView  onTabClose="PF('confirmation').show();return false;">
        <p:tab title="test tab" closable="true" >
           // Some inputs controls here
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

... but I'm agree a built-in confirm would be very usefully